# Reset the running Total in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a pay details sheet where the amount of earnings are shown along with the employee number.I have a distinct count of employees and a running total of all earnings as well.What I need is reset the Running Total to zero when ever the distinct count of employees is 3.
[image]

Comment: You need to write in formula in reset of running total...have you tried that

Comment: Got it Siva... lot of thanks

Comment: No Problem... you are welcome :)